# Is it possible to protect the content (eg video files) in a TideSDK application?

Tags: html, video, tidesdk, drm, multiplatform

I would like to create a video jukebox which runs from a USB stick for PC and Mac.  One requirement is that the video files themselves are not easily copyable from the USB stick by the casual user (although I realise video can be captured other ways).

TideSDK already does most of what I want in terms of building the menus and other content, but I'm not sure if it would allow me to protect the video files? Is there any encryption layer I could take advantage of within this SDK to protect the video files?

I'm not a TideSDK developer currently, so if there's another (multi-platform) solution which might solve the same problem then I'm open to other ideas, but it must be based around HTML5 video.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about your specific question, but like you I am wanting a cross-browser Html desktop solution. The people who worked on tideSDK are presently working on TideKit which seems to be better in many ways (including mobile etc). So you might want to ask them directly:

https://twitter.com/TideKit

They say it will be a purchased product, but annoyingly they have not said how much yet, although they have said it will be affordable for everyone. They have said its about 3 months or so away.

Comment: Ahh OK.. I hadn't realised that TideKit was replacing it. Can't tell if the project's still active as their blog (oddly) has no dates on it so it might be months old.

Comment: Unfortunately though, I can't really wait for anything - I need to start working on this within the next couple of weeks.

Comment: I said 3 months, but if you read their twitter they are talking weeks (said on Jan 15th). So keep it in mind. They respond very quickly to twitter messages, so if you asked your question there, you could rule-in or rule-out the possibility of TideKit.

Comment: But that's until the waiting list opens I think - not when the product is released :)

Comment: Thanks though - I'm now chatting with them on Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can... if you mix it with node.js and serve your video from there. I have already finish a work in a function that loads in node.js the path of my user's app projects (an user can create a project, and at certain point I had to use node.js to create a webserver pointing to the user's project folder, and from them I access the things I may need.

Hopefully when Tidekit is up, we can have something like app-storage:// to place there temporary objects to access them.